# Runtime error when accessing other controller's element in Java/Scala

Tags: java, scala, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm using Java Scene Builder to design the GUI and I have 2 controller (`Controller1` and `Controller2`) and 2 FXML files (`fxml1` applies `Controller1` and `fxml2` applies `Controller2`)

Since I'm planning to access the field on `Controller2` to be modified after I call an event on `Controller1`, I created a variable called `foo` that is of type `Controller2` inside `Controller1` class.

I have a method `someMethod(arg)` in `Controller2` class to be accessed by `Controller1` when a button is pressed.

So in the body of the `Controller1` , I typed `foo.someMethod(someArg)` and it compiles fine.
However, during runtime I'm getting an error when the action method/event (in Controller1)containing the operations `foo.someMethod(someArg)` is called.

The error (note that this error code is generated before I rename the controller classess and fxml files) :

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at eventhandling.RegistrationLogin$Controller$$anonfun$login$1.apply$mcVI$sp(RegistrationLogin.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:166)
    at eventhandling.RegistrationLogin$Controller.login(RegistrationLogin.scala:50)
    at eventhandling.RegistrationLogin.login(RegistrationLogin.scala:21)
    ... 58 more
```

From a quick google search, the error seems to suggest that it's a reflection type of error. Does that mean I have to implement reflection in order to get it to work?

EDIT : According to James_D, the error is due to NullPointerException.
Apparently I only created variable of type Controller2 but it wasn't referred to the Controller2 instance created. 
So in Controller1 class, I typed (in scala language) : `var foo = fxml2.getController[Controller2]()`. It assigns the controller instance used by fxml2 to the variable called bar. But now I got an error that still says NullPointerException. Here are some part of the code containing the instance assignment :

```
 @sfxml
class Controller1(
    ... ,
    private val foo=fxml2.getController[UserEventController]()
    ){
    ...
    def onButtonClick(e : ActionEvent) {
     foo.someMethod(someArg) //someMethod code implementation is in Controller2 class
    }
    }
```

Comment: This is a `NullPointerException`. It has nothing to do with reflection. It would help if you showed some code: in particular how you are getting the reference to the `Controller2` instance that is created by the `FXMLLoader` into `Controller1`.

Comment: Apparently I did not refer the variable of type Controller2 to the Controller2 instance created, which explains the NullPointerException. So in Controller1 class, I did (in scala language) : var foo = fxml2.getController[Controller2](). It assigns the controller instance used by fxml2 to the variable called bar. But now I got an error that still says NullPointerException. I just uploaded part of my code in my edit section.